# Load Data infile command in MySQL not working

Tags: mysql, load, load-data-infile

I am using load data local infile command to load large 9GB file into SQL .

but load data infile command status is showing "Reading file" and command is not getting completed. Is there any problem with line terminator? I am using line terminator \r\n.

Even if use wrong terminator file should be completed with empty results but command is not completing.

Comment: You should add the command you are trying to use and a few rows from the top of the csv file and the table definition of he table you are trying to load to. (all as text). Also what environment are you working in (windows, linux etc), what version of mysql are you on.

Comment: Thank for reply. My load data infile command took 15 minutes to process 50000 rows file . Till yesterday my command used to complete in 1min. I can see some other large queries are running in my sql because of that reason my load data infile is slow?

Comment: ' I can see some other large queries are running in my sql because of that reason my load data infile is slow' - there's a good chance that is the case

Comment: When I tried to kill the command , command in status rollbacking for one hour and rolling back also taking time , do you know the reason why?